# obtain values from ngrx store into local variable in Angular 14

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm still new to NGRX. I have finally got records into store as can be seen from my screenshot below using the Redux Devtools.

[image]

I now want to obtain the basket records to allow me to remove an item from the basket.

I have declared a variable to pull the basket data into:

```
 basketPhoto$: Observable<Photo>[] = [];
```

then I have a click event that passes the photo details that I want to remove, lets say I've passed the photo with an id 0f 3 in. I know I need to obtain the index '1' in this case before splicing it from the basket. So I first need to obtain the index value of me record.

I thought I could do something like:

```
RemoveFromBasket(photo: Photo) {
    this.basketPhoto$ = this.basketStore.pipe(select(basket => basket.basket));
  
  }
```

as my starter to get all the records from the basket, so that I can find the position of my record, but I get a red line under basketPhoto$. basketStore is defined in my constructor.

```
 constructor(private store: Store, private basketStore: Store<{ basket: Photo[] }>) { }
```

******** Update ********

following on from @wlf answer I have created an Action:

```
export const getBasket = createAction('[Basket Component] getBasket', props<{ id: number}>());
```

extended my reducer:

```
export const initialBasketState: Array<Photo> = [];

export const basketReducer = createReducer(   
initialBasketState,   
on(basketDetail, (state, { basket }) => { return [...state, basket] }  ),   
on(getBasket, (state, { id }) => ({ ...state, basket: state.splice(state.findIndex(m => m.id === id)  )})   ), );
```

and I now call the action:

```
 this.basketStore.dispatch(getBasket({ id: photo.id}));
```

Now when make the call, I receive an error

> cannot delete property '1' of [object array]

Comment: Create a selector: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors or if you’re using feature creators https://ngrx.io/guide/store/feature-creators#using-feature-creator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removal logic belongs in your reducer rather than your component.

1. Create an action for removing the photo:

`const removePhotoClicked = createAction('remove photo clicked', props<{id: number}>());`

2. Dispatch that action when button is clicked with relevant id
3. Handle the removal in your reducer:

```
export const designerReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(removePhotoClicked , (state, { id }) => ({
    ...state,
    basket: /* remove the basket with given id */
  })),
);
```

Thus there is no need to '*obtain the basket records to allow me to remove an item from the basket*`. But if you do for some other reason, use a selector.

Comment: changed my reducer to be `on(getBasket, (state, { id }) => state.filter((photo) => photo.id !== id)` now works. Thank you.